# Angular directive to load JS files for the other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to minimize js/css/html footrpint for the user and to load only the files really needed. I've utilized RequireJS for that. 
For my templates I'm trying to implement someting similar to
**using** section in C# or ***///< reference path='...' >*** in TypeScript
But somehow depending on my template content it does or doesn't instantiate **depends-on** directive depending on template I have:

Works:

```
<depends-on path="..\..\test"></depends-on>
<login-form></login-form>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<depends-on path="..\..\test"></depends-on>
<login-form></login-form>
<other-directive></other-directive>
```

Doesn't work:

```
  <div>
     <depends-on path="..\..\test"></depends-on>
     <login-form></login-form>
  </div>
```

I'm obviously missing the way Angular parses and processes templates.
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was that it didn't wait until all directive template depends on are loaded. To ensure dependencies are loaded, dependent code should be in callback passed to require function.